# How can I write the CMakeLists.txt to add .mlmodel to xcode project

Tags: cmake, coreml, mlmodel

I have a `detect_model.mlmodel` which is trained by myself. I want to use it in xcode, but I don't wanna to add it into my xcode project manually. I have tried to write CMakeLists.txt to manage my xcode project. But how can I write in the CMake file to add `detect_model.mlmodel` into my xcode project and generate the `detect_model.h` header file?

I have tried to use `set(mlmodel detect_model.mlmodel)` and `add_library(dst ${mlmodel})`, but it is not correct.

The expected result is that I can use CMake to add `detect_model.mlmodel` into xcode project and generate the `detect_model.h` automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably need to add a custom rule that calls `coremlc` to generate the .h abd .m files and the .mlmodelc folder.

This is how you'd do it from Terminal:

```
mkdir output
xcrun coremlc compile YourModel.mlmodel output
xcrun coremlc generate Model.mlmodel output
```

You also need to add a rule to copy the .mlmodelc folder into the app bundle.

Comment: Great! It worked. Thanks for your help.
Furthermore,  whether there is a tool to do the time profile of mlmodel's each layer, I want to know which network layer takes the most time. The Apple coreml tools don't have this function.

Comment: Furthermore, 《Core ML Survival Guide》is really a proper book. It help me to learn much about coreml.  Great job!

Comment: @YiZhaoYanBo do you by chance have the XCode you wrote to handle this ?